# uncalled variables

Tags: compilation, lisp

I am trying to get started with Lisp and I have some (messy) code that i want to be able to ask the user for a title and url.

Save them in a variable, and then print them out when called. I am running into troubles though. First of all i don't know how to compile my program to run it. Also, the one time when i did run it i got an error about the variable title being uncalled. Can anyone help me with either of these things? Sorry i can't give you more information about the error.

```
;;Define a function called make-cd that takes four parameters
(defun make-url( title url ))
    (list :title title :url url)

;;In the make-url function create a plist that takes the passed values


;; Define global variable db and set its value to nil
(defvar *db* nil)

;; Define a function that takes one paramter and pushes it to the make-url func.
;;(defun add-url (url) (push url *db*))

;; Define a function that takes the *db* variable and makes the output pretty
(defun dump-db ()
   (dolist (url *db*)
       (format t "~{~a:~10t~a~%~}~%" url)))

(defun prompt-read (prompt)
  (format *query-io* "~a: " prompt)
  (force-output *query-io*)
  (read-line *query-io*))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have provided contains errors and will not compile. The error is in your definition of make-url. The proper definition should be:

```
(defun make-url( title url )
      (list :title title :url url))
```

Notice the difference in parenthesis placements.

In your code you had an additional parenthesis following the parameter list. This closed the defun, causing make-url to be evaluated as a function with no body. The next line was then evaluated as a call to the built-in function list. The arguments were evaluated, and an error was encountered when it attempted to find a value for title. There is no binding in the global environment, a binding for title only exists within the body of make-url.

Also, your definition of add-url is commented out. A semi-colon begins a comment in Lisp.

How to compile and run your program depends on what compiler you are using. If you are using SBCL the function is [sb-ext:save-lisp-and-die](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/Saving-a-Core-Image.html). A simple program like this would usually be run in a Read-Eval-Print-Loop(REPL), and most compilers will enter one when started. If you have SBCL installed you can start a repl by entering the command 'SBCL' to the command prompt. If your code is in an external file you can then load that using [Load](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_load.htm).

Comment: Are you asking why I stated that the code in the question will not compile? The expression (list :title title :url url) will not compile if title or url is unbound in the enclosing environment. If it is entered as shown in the question it be evaluated in the global environment and will signal an error because title is unbound. I think that is what the OP meant when he said he "got an error about the variable title being uncalled."

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help.

Lisp programs aren't always distributed in compiled form. Having your program as just the source code is even better then only having the FASL (that's how Lisp binaries are called) because it makes it easier to fix problems if they are found later.

Traditionally, more complex programs, are arranged by means of ASDF package `asdf:defsystem` macro. You can read more about it here: http://common-lisp.net/~mmommer/asdf-howto.shtml . You can find examples on the internet, of how this is usually done through using [Quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/) and looking into its `~/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/<name of the program>/` directory to see how other programs are arranged.

Once system is defined by `asdf:defsystem`, you would use `asdf:oos` to "operate" on it, that is load it. However, Quicklisp has become a very popular and easy to use utility for working with Lisp systems (it uses ASDF package underneath too). So, considering you have it, you would then `(ql:quickload "your-system")`.

In order to make your system available locally through Quicklisp, I'd recommend doing it this way: In your `$HOME` directory (on Linux it is usually aliased with tilde `~`) in the file: `~/.config/common-lisp/source-registry.conf` (you may need to create one, if it's not there already), add something like:

```
(:source-registry
 (:tree (:home "quicklisp/quicklisp/"))
 (:tree (:home "Projects/my-project/"))
 :inherit-configuration)
```

The above would imply that `~/Projects/my-project/` directory contains a system definition file (*.asd), where you have described what files belong to the system and instructed on how to load them etc.

For other options for adding local projects, read the [Quicklisp FAQ](http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/faq.html)

For more information about source-registry.conf file format read [ASDF manual](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#Controlling-where-ASDF-searches-for-systems).

This is a bit involved at the beginning, so I'd advise you to just install one project using Quicklisp and study how it is made. Alexandria could be a good start - besides being a generally useful package, it isn't very large and illustrates the matter very well, IMO.

Comment: "Traditionally" arranged by ASDF? ASDF is relatively new.

Comment: @Kaz About 10 years, I think